# How to redirect output of Windows batch scripts inside a Chef Coobkook into a file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, chef-infra, cookbook

For example in this simple cookbook recipe:

```
batch "Clear_OS_Agent" do
    code <<-EOH

@echo on
dir C:\
@echo off

    EOH

    action :run
```

When I run `chef-client.bat` on a Windows node, I can get the result of `dir C:\`

But when I redirect in into a file `chef-client.bat > C:\chef_log.txt` , there are only the general `chef-client.bat` output over there, without the result of `dir C:\`.

Answer (score 1):

Do the redirect inside your recipe, not when you run chef-client like:

```
code <<-EOH

@echo on
dir C:\ > C:\chef_log.txt
@echo off

EOH
```

You can probably see the results of your run how you were doing it originally if you crank up the debug as well like:

```
chef-client.bat -l debug > C:\chef_log.txt
```

Edit:

If you have multiple commands you want redirected to the same log file you can do the following so you don't have to explicitly redirect each line:

```
(
 echo one
 echo two
 echo three
 dir C:\
) > C:\test.txt
```

Comment: I've tried this. It did not include batch script output in debug log. And the actual script would be long, so it is not convenient to redirect each command line explicitly.